# Reload PrimeJS highlighted code Angular app

Tags: angular, syntax-highlighting, prism.js

I have the next question..
I have an Angular 4+ app and I'm using PrimeJS to handle syntax highlighting (I followed Tero's tutorial https://auralinna.blog/post/2017/code-syntax-highlighting-with-angular-and-prismjs). The problem I have is as follow:

In my component template I have the next code:

```
<pre><code [ngClass]="languageClass">{{ text }}</code></pre>
```

as you can see, I'm making a binding to handle different code and format according to some conditions in the component.. For some reason when the `text` and `languageClass` properties change, it is not being reflected on the template. The highlighted code get stucked with the very first value setted in the component.
Any idea how to solve this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finally solve it by calling the template change detection manually as soon as the code property binding change.. the code looks something like:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, .... } from '@angular/core';

@Component({....})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
    ...
    getSomeText() {
        this.text = null;
        this.ref.detectChanges();
        ...
        this.text = '<foo></foo>';
    }
}
```

And the component template:

```
<pre *ngIf="bodyText !== null"><code>{{ text }}</code></pre>
```

As you can see the `<pre></pre>` tag will dissapear as soon as the property `text` change to null. Then it will be rendered again with the new value to be highlighted.

Comment: just wanted to add you helped me 3 years later on Angular 9+ to solve this problem and your solution was the only one that worked after trying many other solution proposals

Comment: sounds great @hreimer! I'm glad to know you find it helpful!